# Is too much memory allocation in Instruments bad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management, instruments

I am playing around with Instruments. And I just recorded/profiled for memory leaks, I had very few memory leaks, but an overwhelming amount of allocations just keep going even when my app just opened. Here is a screenshot after using the app for less than 10 seconds.

[image: AFTER 10 SECONDS???]

And as I keep using the app it just keeps increasing and increasing.

The weirdest part is most of the allocations are coming from classes I don't know like:

Foundation

Altitude

lbdispatch.dylib

But it could be from the SBJson and the other classes I imported and added for JSon and XML.

But is this a lot of memory allocations? Is too much bad???

Comment: I don't know how much memory being used from just the screenshot. However, if the memory taken up is being used for the current screen, then it shouldn't be a problem. You can look at the list of objects and find whatever object that shouldn't be there to remove.

Comment: Just an update... it was about 150 mb in 5 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends on what you are doing, if you allocate for example a lot of strings, lets say you allocate 1000 strings these allocation perse are not bad, but it depends on your logic view of your application, if you really need all the strings at once and you need them to be allocated and alive through all the steps of your application, then you dont have anything to do, your application just needs alot of memory,

However on the other hand, you may find some other ways to logically structure your application, like for example you could only allocate each of the 1000 string once you need it.

A very abstract answer is, if your app requires a lot of memory and there is no way to use some techniques such as lazy loading, or caching, then you dont have any other solution

But if you can restructure your application to use lazy loading, caching, allocation pools it would bee better

Please note: that you could let iOS sdk help you, by implementing correctly the memory warning callbacks in your application, in such a way that whenever you receive a warning, you start releasing any resource that you dont currently need

Answer (score 1):

Also, do you have Zombies on? Zombies default to not actually removing any allocations, so memory is never deallocated. Always test for memory leaks with Zombies off.